# Array of Custom Objects MongoDB Schema

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I need to create an array of objects with two fields (no methods needed) in mongoDB so that the document has a field that is an array of the these objects with two fields. I have no idea what the schema syntax should be however. How would I go about this?

Also:
Can I just declare an document with an array and fill it in with javascript objects created at run time? 
Or should I declare the custom object in the Schema for the array holding document?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Given that your previous questions and this one are about mongoose schema usage then you would be better of showing what you are trying to do, even if the syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The following is an example creating an object with an array of object, each with 2 fields. Is this what you are looking for?

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.3
connecting to: test
> 
> 
> db.test.insert({myArray: [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b:4}]})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.test.findOne()
{
"_id" : ObjectId("53adc9301e7d2620fc75f8c7"),
"myArray" : [
    {
        "a" : 1,
        "b" : 2
    },
    {
        "a" : 3,
        "b" : 4
    }
]
}
```